# Override TranslationsCacheWarmer service

Tags: symfony

I have an application that contains a lot of translation resources for a lot of different languages. The warmup process takes a long time because of this.

I only support the translation of my site in a few languages, so I'd like to avoid generating catalogues for all the languages that I don't support.

What I did:

I overrode the TranslationsCacheWarmer to use my own translator. This is a custom translator that decorates the default translator but overrides the warmup method to only warmup files that are part of the locales that I support.

The problem is that the default warmer still runs generating files for all the locales.

This is the code that contains the custom translator: https://gist.github.com/marcosdsanchez/e8e2cd19031a2fbcd894

and here's how I'm defining the services:

```
<service id="web.translation.public_languages_translator" class="X\Translation\PublicLanguagesTranslator" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="translator.default" />
    <argument type="collection">%chess.translation.public_languages%</argument>
</service>

<service id="translation.warmer" class="Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\CacheWarmer\TranslationsCacheWarmer" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="web.translation.public_languages_translator" />
    <tag name="kernel.cache_warmer" />
</service>
```

I'm using symfony 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something different to get the same result. Instead of trying to create a custom CacheWarmer, I created a compiler pass and modified the definition of the 'options' argument. In this compiler pass, I removed all the files that don't have the locale or language code.

Code:

```
<?php

namespace X\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use X\Entity\I18nLanguage;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class TranslatorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('translator.default');
        $options = $definition->getArgument(3);
        $keys = array_keys($options['resource_files']);
        $locales = I18nLanguage::PUBLIC_LOCALES;
        $langCodes = array();
        foreach (I18nLanguage::PUBLIC_LOCALES as $locale) {
            $langCodes[] = substr($locale, 0, strpos($locale, '_'));
        }
        $localesAndLangCodes = array_merge($locales, $langCodes);
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (!in_array($key, $localesAndLangCodes, true)) {
                unset($options['resource_files'][$key]);
            }
        }

        $arguments = $definition->getArguments();
        $definition->setArguments(array($arguments[0], $arguments[1], $arguments[2], $options));
    }
}
```

That did the trick for me and I can also apply other optimizations like the removal of loaders, etc.